# Angular push function creates new document, but none of the field values were created

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app that I'm working on that needs to push 2 field values (title, content) to a mongodb.  When the Post Article button is pressed it seems to create a new article in the DB, but the title and content fields are not populated as well.  It's like there is a disconnect between the form and object being posted.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!!

Here's my create component html.

```
<div class="article-container">
<form [formGroup]="articleFrm" (ngSubmit)="addArticle(article, articleFrm.value)" *ngIf="articleFrm">
    <div class="row expanded">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <label>Article Title
                <input type="text" name="title" [formControl]="articleFrm.controls['title']" formControlName="title">
            </label>
            <div class="alert" *ngIf="!articleFrm.controls['title'].valid && articleFrm.controls['title'].touched">
                You must specify a title that's at least 10 characters long.
            </div>

            <label>Description
                <textarea name="content" id="content" required [formControl]="articleFrm.controls['content']" formControlName="content"></textarea>
            </label>
            <div class="alert" *ngIf="!articleFrm.controls['content'].valid && articleFrm.controls['content'].touched">
                You must specify a content that's at least 10 characters long.
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="cta-btn filled" value="Post Article" [disabled]="!articleFrm.valid">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's my create component TrueScript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

// Article imports
import { ArticleService } from '../article.service';
import { Article } from '../article';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-create',
  templateUrl: './article-create.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-create.component.css']
})
export class ArticleCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  articleFrm: FormGroup;
  articles: Array<Article> = [];

  constructor(private _articleService: ArticleService, private router: Router, private aR: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._articleService.getArticles()
      .subscribe(res => this.articles = res);

    this.articleFrm = this.fb.group({
      'title' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(45)])],
      'content' : [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)])]
    });
  }

  addArticle(article: Article) {
    this._articleService.insertArticle(article)
      .subscribe(newArticle => {
          this.articles.push(newArticle);
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
      })
  }

}
```

And lastly here's my article service code.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Article } from './article';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticleService {

  result:any;

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getArticles() {
    return this._http.get('/api/articles')
      .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json()));
  }

  getArticle(id) {
    return this._http.get("/api/articles/"+id)
      .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json()));
  }

  insertArticle(post: Article) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this._http.post('/api/article/create', JSON.stringify(post), options)
      .pipe(map(result => this.result = result.json()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I get frustrated and decide to post here, 5 minutes later I find my own answer.  I spent the last hour on this and it was simply removing "article" from my component html file in the ngSubmit.